# wrapper returning promise c++

Tags: c++, promise, wrapper

I have the following function:

```
std::future<void> resolve_one() {
        typename std::list<matrix_wrap<T>>::iterator lhs = find_max();
        typename std::list<matrix_wrap<T>>::iterator rhs = lhs;
        ++rhs;
        typename std::list<matrix_wrap<T>>::iterator result=matrices.emplace(lhs,matrix<T>(lhs->get_height(),rhs->get_width()));

        auto lambda = [&]() {
            do_multiply(*result,*lhs,*rhs);
            matrices.erase(lhs);
            matrices.erase(rhs);
        };
        return std::async(std::launch::async, lambda);

    }
```

My teacher said I have to modify the wrapper class I wrote, in order to return a promise of a result of do_multiply, because I need to have concurrent operations for example in (A+B)*(C+D), (A+B) and (C+D) are performed asynchronously before the final multiplication . I litteraly don't know how to modify it, could anyone help me? thanks. You can find my wrapper class here: [matrix_wrap](https://pastebin.com/raw/aqpBfUsq)

Comment: The code your teacher wants you to change sounds like it is part of the code not shown

Comment: Also note that this code is looks unsafe, as you can access the `matrix` that `result` points to before it has been calculated. Also you are capturing references to local values, they will become invalid after `resolve_one` returns. Just capture by value.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `std::future<void>` to wrap calculating a value. You should be operating on `std::future<matrix_wrapper<T>>` values as much as possible.

```
using matrix_future = std::future<matrix_wrapper<T>>;
matrix_future operator *(matrix_future lhs, matrix_future rhs)
{
    return std::async(std::launch::async, [lhs=std::move(lhs), rhs=std::move(rhs)] mutable ()
    {
        const auto & l = lhs.get();
        const auto & r = rhs.get();
        assert(l.get_width() == r.get_height());

        matrix_wrap<T> result = *matricies.emplace(l.get_height(), r.get_width());
        do_multiply(result, l, r);
        return result;
    });
}

using matrix_future = std::future<matrix_wrapper<T>>;
matrix_future operator +(matrix_future lhs, matrix_future rhs)
{
    return std::async(std::launch::async, [lhs=std::move(lhs), rhs=std::move(rhs)] mutable ()
    {
        const auto & l = lhs.get();
        const auto & r = rhs.get();
        assert(l.get_dims() == r.get_dims());

        matrix_wrap<T> result = *matricies.emplace(l.get_dims());
        do_add(result, l, r);
        return result;
    });
}
```

You can easily wrap a value in a future using `std::promise` (or `std::experimental::make_ready_future` if available)

```
matrix_future make_ready_future(matrix_wrapper<T> mat)
{
     std::promise<matrix_wrapper<T>> prom;
     prom.set_value(std::move(mat));
     return prom.get_future();
}
```

This then gets used like

```
int main()
{
    auto A = get_A_async(/* ... */);
    auto B = make_ready_future(matrix(/* ... */));
    auto C = make_ready_future(get_C(/* ... */));
    auto D = A * C;

    auto result = (A + B) * (C + D);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I was on holyday! Thank you for your answer! Do you think I could call make_ready_future in another function which calls the other functions (not the main function)?I want to make simpler the main function because my teacher wants to write his own (I don't know how he will write it)

Comment: Hi!I tried to modify my code as you suggest, but I have this error:  
' error: use of deleted function 'std::future<matrix_wrap<int> >::future(const std::future<matrix_wrap<int> >&) '
Why? How am I supposed to solve it? Thanks

Comment: @MMM are you trying to copy the result to somewhere? `std::future` is move only (like `std::unique_ptr`). You can `share` the future if you need copies.

Comment: I tried using your suggestion and I wrote this: `operator *(std::future<matrix_wrap<T>>& lhs, std::future<matrix_wrap<T>>& rhs)`, but then the compiler gives an error on const auto & l = lhs.get(); and also on async it says there's an error of conversion (what??)

Comment: sorry I know that my last comment was unclear, I want to explain better the probelm. Here you can find my code:  [ wrapper class](https://pastebin.com/raw/hzr7vh8e) , [operations class] (https://pastebin.com/raw/N4zE53XB). You can find the errors [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/DY9nujrB). I think I've done something wrong when I tried to pass the matrices with &. How can I solve it?

Comment: Oh, I've worked out what it is. The `lhs` and `rhs` are members of the lambda, and by default it's `operator()` is const.

Comment: So how do I solve the problem? by removing const in `const auto & l = lhs.get();` ? 'cause I don't think it is the solution, probably I  misunderstood, did I?

Comment: mm ok this is the way: the errors are almost solved, I still have a problem with async:  `error: could not convert 'std::async(std::launch, _Fn&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Fn = operator*(std::future<matrix_wrap<T> >&, std::future<matrix_wrap<T> >&) [with T = int]::<lambda()>; _Args = {}; ...'`  (sorry but I was really lost)

Comment: Oops, it's a `matrix_wrap`, not a `matrix`